# Unity Issue an WebGL: FSBTool ERROR: Failed with error code 80004001

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is only with WebGL

Errors during import of AudioClip Assets/Audio/background.wav:
FSBTool ERROR: Failed with error code 80004001

FSBTool ERROR: Failed encoding audio clip '/Assets/Audio/background.wav' to AAC. Possibly the file is too short. Try to append silence such that the length becomes greater than 256 samples.

**I can't add the audio click on WebGL, but on others platforms work  perfectly.**

[I can't add the audio click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vsA4.png)

**Please help.**

Comment: Is the clip too short as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that the Audio-Sequence is too short. Try adding silence (as suggested) to increase the samples of your file.